# Can't position View and Image at bottom of Scene

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I have a scene called **Login** that has two main views: **Center** and **BG**.

**BG** contains an image asset, and I'm trying to get the view to the back of the screen (with **Center** on top).

It looks correct in XCode, however when I simulate it, it appears on top, blocking the rest of the page:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I move the **BG** view to the back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my eye it seems that the problem is in the constraints or alpha levels. As Center is placed higher than BG in the view hierarchy, it should be visible if both of these are set correctly.

Comment: This was it - the alpha for BG was 1, however the alpha for Center was 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Center and BG both are subviews, have you tried following func on UIView ?

```
func insertSubview(_ view: UIView,
      aboveSubview siblingSubview: UIView)
```

Here the Apple documentation link - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview:aboveSubview:

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still getting used to Swift and managing the view programmatically - what of those are placeholders, and how can I find the names to fill them in?